# Magento - Show same item with different colors underneath the item

Tags: magento

i’m new to magento and was wondering if someone can help me. 
i have a product that comes in multiple colors, but if i set it up as a configurable product it just gives the user the option of choosing a different color (but doesn’t show an image to him/her)

what i would like to do is have the other colors appear underneath just like up sells would (the same design) 
if anyone can help me i would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Simple Configurable Products extension by Organic Internet, as available for free on Magento Connect and your problem should be solved.

Comment: firstly thanks a lot for responding i greatly appreciate the expert help and advice

Comment: are you talking about this? https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple/

Comment: i want to explain a little better what i want to do please look at this link http://www.townappliance.com/Products.asp?cat=11 and this link (the product itself) http://www.townappliance.com/product.asp?cat=11&pid=3890&pn=ABB1922FEB the user is able to see right away the different colors that there are and see them how do i do this in magento

Comment: Sorry for slow reply - new here, however, that extension should help you achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to store images for each color of the project. With JS, you could auto-select color options on the page, and still make use of a configurable product for this purpose. You'll need to do significant template alteration to make this work.

Another approach is to use simple products (which you've already created in this case), and list them directly in the catalog. With Magento's cross-sell functionality, you can tag the products to each other and provide links between product pages for each color. Obviously, this involves more navigation for the user, but does allow you to manage each product independently.

Both of these methods will retain normal product relationships and track inventory for each color of a product, so they are preferable to solutions that involve hacking the framework.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joseph Mastey

Comment: thanks for responding i will look in to what you are suggesting your advice is greatly appreciated